# python pil module name pronlems

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I wrote a code like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PIL import Image
import os
path1 = os.getcwd()
path3 = path1 + '/Downloads/'
path2 = '/home/ulkar/Desktop/testing/'
if not os.path.exists(path2):
    os.makedirs(path2)
for file in os.listdir(path3):
    filename = os.path.splitext(path2 + file)
    imfile = Image.open(path3 + file)
    dooo = imfile.rotate(90).save(filename[0] + '1' , 'PNG')
~
```

But instead of example.jpg -> example1.png, I see example1, example11, example111, etc. as names after splitext
what is the reason for that?

Comment: Try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Comment: You're calling `save()` with `filename[0]`, which is the bare filename without the extension.

Comment: What is `filename`? Try printing it.

Comment: Could you try with file extension? E.g.: .png

Answer (score 1):

It was related to OS cache if I am not mistaken. I have changed the folder name and it has created the new folder. And it worked. example.jpg -> example1.png

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the Pillow source code for the save() function, and it does not guarantee that the extension of the saved file will match the image type.

If you supply a filename with an extension, it will infer the image type from the extension.  This can be overriden by passing the image type as a second argument.  But it will not change the extension for you; you have to do that yourself.

The docs do not suggest that the function will change the filename for you.  The Pillow docs are often a bit sketchy but in this case, there is no reason to expect the function to automatically produce the desired filename for you.

Comment: Actually it changes the extension, but the problem is that let us say the name of the file is test.jpg and it saves this file to the folder shown in the code as test1.png, test11.png, test111.png, test1111.png, test11111.png. And it is for all the files.